# Testing-library Cannot set property error of [object Object] which has only a getter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-test, testing-library

I'm working in a Angular application and I'm using testing-library for testing, and this is the situation:

I have this component:

```
<div class="inner-card" *ngIf="!error && !loading && hasInv">
  <div class="chart-xpto">
    <abc-port-chart-donut
      *ngIf="dadosChart"
      [legenda]="true"
      [dataset]="dadosChart"
      [largura]="donutHeight"
      [altura]="donutWidth"
      identifier="chart-xpto-abc"
    ></abc-port-chart-donut>
  </div>
```

This is the .ts of the component: (As you can see it extends a BaseComponent)

```
export class XptoComponent extends XptoBaseComponent implements OnInit {
```

And this is the base component:

```
export class XptoBaseComponent extends XptoCommonComponent implements OnInit {
[...]
  get error(): boolean {
    if (
      this.service.response.responseStatus === HTTP_STATUS_CODE.BAD_REQUEST ||
      this.service.response.responseStatus === HTTP_STATUS_CODE.NOT_FOUND
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  get loading(): boolean {
    return !this.service.response.responseStatus && !this.service.response.responseError;
  }

  get hasInv(): boolean {
    if (this.service.response.responseStatus === HTTP_STATUS_CODE.NO_CONTENT) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

As you can see, the propertiers that I need to render my component (error, loading and hasInv) are only getters and they come from the basecomponent...

This is how I'm trying to do my test:

```
it('teste render', async () => {
  const {container} = await render(XptoComponent, {
    componentProperties: {
      error: false,
      loading: false,
      hasInvestment: true
    }
  })
  const abc = container.querySelector(".inner-card");
  expect(abc).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

But when I try to test in this way, I

**    TypeError: Cannot set property error of [object Object] which has only a getter**

So my issue is, how can I set these properties on my component and be able to render correctly the component in my test using testing-library?

Comment: You can't, because you haven't defined a setter for those properties.  Since all of those properties are dependent on a service, it would probably be best to configure the service to return appropiate values (as a mock)

Comment: Hey Mike! thanks!
How could I mock properties that are only getters? I've tried to do that, but I was not successfully yet...

Comment: You really can't. You can a) spy on the getters and return your own values or b) configure a service mock to return the appropiate values for your test.

Comment: I've tried a spy but I've been not successfully either...
I tried the spy in this way...
jest.spyOn(XptoComponent, 'error').mockReturnValue(false)

Comment: try `jest.spyOn(XptoComponent, 'error', 'get').mockReturnValue(false) `

Comment: did not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your properties are get only thus assigning new values wont work.

But there is still a solution, which might work for you. Your get properties rely on an injected service ***this.service.response.responseStatus***:

```
get error(): boolean {
    if (
      // this service can be mocked
      this.service.response.responseStatus === HTTP_STATUS_CODE.BAD_REQUEST ||
      this.service.response.responseStatus === HTTP_STATUS_CODE.NOT_FOUND
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

So instead of setting the state with componentProperties like here:

```
componentProperties: {
      error: false,
      loading: false,
      hasInvestment: true
    }
```

You could provide a mocked version of your service like here:

```
 const {container} = await render(XptoComponent, {
    providers: [{
       provide: YourServiceType,
       useValue: { response: { responseStatus: HTTP_STATUS_CODE.NO_CONTENT } }
     }]
  })
```

This would affect the result of your get only properties in desired way ->

```
error: false,
loading: false,
hasInvestment: true
```